# Gulp.src throws 'First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.'

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm stacked here with problem with gulp.src, which is only accepts String containing exact file like

```
gulp.src('index.html')
```

or array of strings

```
gulp.src(['index.html', 'home.html', 'products.html'])
```

but can't handle

```
gulp.src('./*.html')
```

or
    gulp.src(['*.html', './**/*.html'])
which is I'm aiming to. 
I'm always getting this error is I put something different as argument from the first two line:

```
[15:48:46] Starting 'wiredep'...
[15:48:46] Finished 'wiredep' after 14 ms
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
```

Can somebody let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
gulp.src('./*.html')
```

and

```
gulp.src(['*.html', './**/*.html'])
```

are valid globs.

**Maybe one of your .html file is empty** and the wiredep plugin tries to load an undefined stream which causes the TypeError.

Comment: This could help: [gulp-clip-empty-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clip-empty-files)

Comment: This makes sense. I was sure argues are valid and was surprised from the error. I'll try it and get to this thread. Thank you. The gulp clip sounds as useful thing

Comment: That was the problem - I had html files without bower include marks. Thank you

Comment: gulp 4 build with npm wiredep package. Someone had auto-generated empty html and I got this error. Thank you!